# Change my Linked List implentation to work on Leetcode problems?

Tags: javascript, data-structures, linked-list, implementation

I'm working on this leetcode problem: https://leetcode.com/problems/delete-node-in-a-linked-list/

> Write a function to delete a node in a singly-linked list. You will not be given access to the head of the list, instead you will be given access to the node to be deleted directly.
>
> It is guaranteed that the node to be deleted is not a tail node in the list.

and I've found this solution:

```
var deleteNode = function (node) {
    node.val = node.next.val;
    node.next = node.next.next;
};
```

This is my Linked List implementaion:

```
class Node {
    constructor(value) {
        this.value = value;
        this.next = null;
    }
}

class LinkedList {
    constructor(value) {
        const newNode = new Node(value);
        this.head = newNode;
        this.tail = this.head;
        this.length = 1;
    }
}
```

I dont't know why it's not working on my LL implemetation.

Comment: @RomainHippeau You can't do that in a singly-linked list without being given the head pointer.

Comment: @RomainHippeau He's copying the value from the next one into the current one before deleting the next.

Comment: If you delete the 2nd-to-last node, it becomes the tail, but `LinkedList.tail` still points to the previous tail.

Comment: And you also don't reduce the length of the `LinkedList` that contains it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the referenced question there is just this node class being used. This is what Leet Code shows in a comment block:

```
/**
 * Definition for singly-linked list.
 * function ListNode(val, next) {
 *     this.val = (val===undefined ? 0 : val)
 *     this.next = (next===undefined ? null : next)
 * }
 */
```

The first issue is that the `val` property is called `value` in your class, so you should change that name where it occurs in the `deleteNode` code.

Secondly, Leet Code does not introduce nor need a linked list class, so that means that all the data you have in your `LinkedList` instance, will have to be kept updated on top of what you would do with just a node class, like the one above.

Actually, by adding a `LinkedList` class with its own properties, you'll have an additional problem: when `deleteNode(node)` is called, you'll have to be sure that `node` is actually a node in *your* linked list instance, and not in some other linked list. What if you have two linked lists? How will you know to which list the node belongs that is passed as argument to `deleteNode`?

Now if we can assume that the `node` argument is a node in your current linked list, we can define `deleteNode` as a method.

A side note: your `LinkedList` constructor immediately creates a node, but this is a bad idea: linked lists can be empty, so start with an empty list (by default), and use the usual addition method(s) to also add the first node.

```js
class Node {
    constructor(value) {
        this.value = value;
        this.next = null;
    }
}

class LinkedList {
    constructor() {
        // A linked list could be empty, so don't create a node
        this.head = null;
        this.tail = null;
        this.length = 0;
    }
    append(val) {  // 
        if (!this.tail) this.head = this.tail = new Node(val);
        else this.tail = this.tail.next = new Node(val);
        this.length++;
    }
    deleteNode(node) {
        node.value = node.next.value; // Use value, not val
        node.next = node.next.next;
        // Also update the linked list properties:
        if (!node.next) this.tail = node;
        this.length--;
    }
    *[Symbol.iterator]() { // A generator to easily output the list's values
        for (let node = this.head; node; node = node.next) {
            yield node.value;
        }
    }
}

// demo
const list = new LinkedList(); 
list.append(1);
list.append(2);
list.append(3);
console.log("initial list:  ", ...list);
list.deleteNode(list.head.next); // Delete the 2
console.log("after deletion:", ...list);
```